# Why is CSS spinning not working on mobile?

Tags: css, html

I want to spin the below image to 360 degree and below css applied on that image:

```
<img src="" alt="" />
```

CSS:

```
.image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin:-60px 0 0 -60px;
    -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

It's working on desktop well but not on mobile? If I have done anything wrong?

Comment: What browser on mobile?

Comment: on every browser..

Comment: Connect your mobile to PC and inspect element using normal browser devtools.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me both on mobile and desktop.

```
.loader {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your spin code might be not working because you haven't coded that correctly. There are some issues in the `@keyframes` animation.

[SEE THE EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/hardenrahul/pen/yzxGWw)